# How to Set Which Server Google Vision Sends its API calls to?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, location, privacy, google-vision

Our client does not let information be sent offshore. This isn't a discussion as to whether this is good policy or not.

I am wondering if there's any way to set the server that you send Google Vision's API calls to. In the same way you can select which server you want in Google's Compute.

Comment: This question is really the wrong way around. If your client is concerned about privacy, sending data to google has a *far* higher risk and exposure than sending data “offshore”

Comment: Agreed, hence my second sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time Google Cloud Vision is a global product and you cannot set a specific region for data processing.

On the following link scroll down to `Global Products`.

[Google Cloud Locations](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/)

Vision OCR offers regional support

[Vision OCR multiregion support](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#regionalization)

AutoML Vision is limited to us-central1 only at this time.